# Vim equivalent of Emacs' open-rectangle

Tags: vim

Emacs has a function called open-rectangle, which allows you to select a rectangular region (i.e. Vim's visual block mode), then hit a key combination to fill that rectangle with spaces, pushing any existing content out to the right:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

This is really useful when working with vertically-aligned columns of text. I feel like I should be able to do this easily in Vim too, using visual block + a search & replace. But I can't seem to figure out why my search & replace isn't bound to my rectangle when I try it.

```
:'<,'>s/\^/    /
```

This actually indents the whole line, instead of opening up this selected region. I've tried replacing:

```
:'<,'>s/\v(.*)/   \1/
```

But that has the same effect. How can I get my pattern to understand that I only want to replace each line in the selected block with spaces + the selected area? Simple replacements like just changing letters work, but using `^` or `.*` doesn't work the way I'd expect.

I am aware of the ability to hit "I" and insert some spaces the drop back into normal mode, but that is harder to judge when you're indenting by a large amount, over many lines.

Comment: @hammar that doesn't seem to do the right thing. It certainly leaves the selected area padded with spaces, but it garbles the text.

Comment: Ah, of course. I actually just figured that out before coming back here. Can you post that as an answer? :) Works perfectly!

Comment: I presume that you're dealing with occurrences in the middle of a line, else would `>` be more efficient.

Comment: Occurrences in the middle of lines, yes.

Comment: I changed the images to make that more obvious, as it wasn't clear what was on the left before ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
yPgvr<Space>
```

This yanks the block and pastes it to duplicate it, then re-selects the original block and replaces it with spaces.

Comment: More efficient: replace `dP` with `y`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan that definitely makes more sense and makes for a less messy undo sequence (if you decide to undo).

Comment: I bound this to `<C-o>` in my vimrc. This has always been one of those things I've missed from Emacs, and now I have it back. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

1. Visual-block select only one column.
2. Hit `nI<Space><Esc>` with `n` being the number of blank columns you want.

Comment: This works with any amount of columns. `I` in block select mode inserts text in each line before the selection, just like `A` appends text in each line after the selection.

Comment: This is a much more general solution. I like it. But do you happen to know where it is documented? I can't find anything on it. (Unfortunately, visual-block mode is fairly poorly documented.)

Comment: "Visual-block select only one column." Well, you can select more if you want... Then too, `nI<Space>` could be replaced with `I` followed by *n* spaces (which may be easier to perceive visually). [Bah, I hate the Markdown implementation used for comments! It's even worse than the one used for formatting questions and answers!]

Comment: This is the way I used to do it, but you have to think, because it's not visual enough. It does work though. I think if you have to count more than about 5 spaces, it just becomes impractical. A key mapping that opens the region based on a visual selection is much easier (see my pictures to see how it's clear what the alignment is).

Comment: @d11wtq: if doing it this way, I'd be more likely to use `I<Space><Space><Space>...<Esc>` than `nI<Space><Esc>`; that way you get to see what you're inserting on the first line.

Comment: Just to be clear, I think that hammar's answer is the right way to go because you don't need to count anything and, once it is mapped, it is very versatile. I just wanted to point out another option that may fit other situations. Also I insist on the "only one column" because it is faster than multiple columns and multiple columns would be useless in this situation anyway. Last point: `nI<Space><Esc>` is more obviously more scalable than `I<Space><Space>…<Esc>`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan yep, that's what I've always done in the past, but it's still harder to see the alignment, as it's only indenting text on the first line, which might be 20+ lines away from the target.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Visual block mode is in fact very thoroughly documented, it is just a little hard to find: See sections [5](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-operators), [6](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-repeat), [7](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-examples) in visual.txt.

Answer (score 2):

As a variation on *romainl*'s answer, I have this:

```
vnoremap <C-Space> I<Space><Esc>gv
```

It allows both insertion of *n* spaces at once via a prepended count, and iterative adding of columns by repeated application of the mapping.